# How to update MySql column from -1 to 1 after login from PHP script

Tags: php, mysql

Before I ask the question, I know there are issues with the SQL Injection, I am going to take care of it most likely with PDO, I am just trying to figure this out for now.

I want PHP to read the status column from MySql and if the status column reads -1 where $username = ($_POST["username"])  I want PHP to initially send them to a "change password" screen and then after its changed send an update script to MySql to update column "status" from the default -1 to 1.

If its 1 I want it to log in as normal and if its -1 I want them to be forced to change their password basically and I am having trouble locating a way to do this.

Im assuming my update query would look something like this

```
$query = "UPDATE login SET status= 1 WHERE user_id='".$username ."' LIMIT 1";
```

My php login script so far

```
<?php
// Include config file
require_once 'LoginConn.php';

// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$username = $password = "";
$username_err = $password_err = "";

// Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

    // Check if username is empty
    if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){
        $username_err = 'Please enter username.';
    } else{
        $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
    }

    // Check if password is empty
    if(empty(trim($_POST['password']))){
        $password_err = 'Please enter your password.';
    } else{
        $password = trim($_POST['password']);
    }

    // Validate credentials
    if(empty($username_err) && empty($password_err)){
        // Prepare a select statement
        $sql = "SELECT username, password FROM scorecardusers WHERE username = ?";

        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);

            // Set parameters
            $param_username = $username;

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                // Store result
                mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

                // Check if username exists, if yes then verify password
                if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){                    
                    // Bind result variables
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $username, $hashed_password);
                    if(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
                        if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password)){
                            /* Password is correct, so start a new session and
                            save the username to the session */


                            session_start();

                            $value= $sql['password'];


                            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;      
                            header("location: Test.php");
                        } else{
                            // Display an error message if password is not valid
                            $password_err = 'The password you entered was not valid.';
                        }
                    }
                } else{
                    // Display an error message if username doesn't exist
                    $username_err = 'No account found with that username.';
                }
            } else{

                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }

        // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }

    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
}
?>
```

UPDATED: I added this to my query and it updates correctly.

```
mysqli_query ($link, "UPDATE Users SET Status = '1' WHERE Status ='-1'and username ='".$username ."' LIMIT 1");
```

If anyone could help me understand how to pull the status area from my sql and redirect them to the change password page if the status =-1 that would be awesome.

I am just trying to figure out how to redirect to change password if Status =-1 in mysql..

SECOND UPDATE: Ive made a second query that checks the information and sends you to the change password log however I know this is not correct. I feel as if I am getting a lot closer to the answer though. The code works as far as getting me to the right screen but its not getting the correct information. I need the username to be a variable based on what the agent puts in. Again, any help here would be really appreciated.

```
        $id_get = "SELECT Status, username FROM scorecardusers WHERE Status = '-1' and username='MyName' LIMIT 1";


        if ($result=mysqli_query($link, $id_get))
        {   

      // Fetch one and one row// check if first time log in
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
   $Status=$row["Status"];
   $username=$row["MyName"];
      if ($Status== "-1" && $username =="MyName");
      var_dump($result);
        header("location: ChangePW.php");

    }
  // Free result set
  mysqli_free_result($result);
}
```

Comment: What issues with SQL injection? This uses prepared statements with placeholder values, if you follow that pattern in your actual code you're fine in that regard, but there's other serious concerns.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in.

Comment: I will take a look into it, however I am using Dreamweaver to build this. Its a  simple login thats going to be used within a closed network. I just need it to redirect to change password if Status column =-1

Comment: As a code editor Dreamweaver is fine, but it's PHP code snippets are atrociously bad and they shouldn't be used. Remember, your "closed network" system today could get opened to the public tomorrow for many reasons, deliberate or accidental. If you build your application correctly the first time, which isn't hard, you won't be exposed to risk in the future.

Comment: One thing to note here is that using `username` as a primary identifier in your user table is problematic. Usernames can and will change even if your rules don't explicitly allow it. Use something like an `AUTO_INCREMENT` identifier internally, a username in URLs and for login purposes. Never recycle automatically generated IDs or you risk cross-linking data from one account to another.

Comment: How can a username change if they all have unique identifiers that never change or repeat? They are not going to have an options to set their username its all predefined. Since thats the case would I still need to use AUTO_Increment? I am looking into AUTO_INCREMENT because I have never actually used it before.

Comment: Not changing or repeating usernames is just policy. What if someone wants their name changed really badly and they get an admin to "fix" it for them? That can create a huge mess. If the name itself is just another field then there's no problem.

Comment: I understand where you are coming from, however I am the only admin and there is no need to change the username, its based off their unique identifiers and everyone gets one and they never are the same. There should be no reason that an ID change would ever be required. Im saying username but really its a unique ID that is attached to the person. If they leave that id is not re-used. The id's are basically Auto Increment.

Answer (score 0):

I added the update query I posted above after the following code. This has solved my problem and accurately check if the user was logged in before, if they have the website directs them to a change password, if they have logged in it send them to the website. I created a separate query to select status and username so it would not interfere with the password. I am assuming this would work with any user name considering it is completely variable as long as they never logged in before it should direct them. If there is any issues with this code id love to know, however it is working correctly for me.

```
$id_get = "SELECT Status, username FROM Users WHERE Status = '-1' and username = ?";




 if($Check = mysqli_prepare($link, $id_get)){
        // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($Check, "s", $param2_username);

        // Set parameters
        $param2_username = $username;
        $param_status=$status;

        // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
        if(mysqli_stmt_execute($Check)){
            // Store result
            mysqli_stmt_store_result($Check);

            if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($Check) == 1){                    
                // Bind result variables


                mysqli_stmt_bind_result($Check, $username, $param2_status);
                if(mysqli_stmt_fetch($Check)){

                   if ($param_status== "-1" && $param2_username == '?');
                        header("location: ChangePassword.php");
                    }
                }


        }

 }
```